# why this sql query does not pass result accurately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want `sum(t1+t2) as d` result publish accurately with `group by tblpersonalInfo.applicantID`, but this query show me d's result with group by `tblpersonalInfo.applicantID` but this query show d's result incrementally.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 

    t1+t2,

    tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId,
    tblPersonalInfo.Applicantname
FROM    (
    SELECT  SUM(tblExpeRange.score)as t2
    FROM    tblexperience
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblExpeRange 
        ON tblexperience.ExpRange=tblExpeRange.expeRange

    GROUP BY tblexperience.ApplicantId
    ) tblexperience,
    ( 
    SELECT  SUM(tblGradPoint.score) AS t1
    FROM    tblAcademicInfo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblGradPoint 
            ON tblAcademicInfo.cgpa=tblGradPoint.[cgpa/division]
    GROUP BY tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
    ) tblAcademicInfo,
    tblPersonalInfo

    INNER JOIN tblCircular 
        ON tblPersonalInfo.Cirname = tblCircular.Cirname
WHERE tblCircular.Cirname=(tblPersonalInfo.Cirname)

RETURN
```

Comment: Why do you have the sum and group by commented out?

Comment: Show the actual query you're having trouble with, not a modified version with big chunks commented out. Anyway, I suspect the problem is with `DISTINCT`. You don't need that if you're grouping.

Comment: ...I've attempted to edit the query to make it more readable but the commented out sections are causing real confusion

Comment: i edit it remove the comment

Comment: What's the relationship of tblexperience with other tables?

Comment: Start by rewriting the query, stick the subqueries in temp tables and check their results first. And finally work on the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about all your query but sounds like you might need to UNION the two sub-queries into one, then you can sum in the `SELECT` clause...

```
SELECT  sum(T) AS d,
        Y.ApplicantId,
        Y.Applicantname
FROM    (
        SELECT  tblexperience.ApplicantId,
                SUM(tblExpeRange.score)as T
        FROM    tblexperience
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblExpeRange 
                  ON tblexperience.ExpRange=tblExpeRange.expeRange
        GROUP BY tblexperience.ApplicantId
        UNION 
        SELECT  tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId,
                SUM(tblGradPoint.score) AS T
        FROM    tblAcademicInfo
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblGradPoint 
                  ON tblAcademicInfo.cgpa=tblGradPoint.[cgpa/division]
        GROUP BY tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
        ) X
        INNER JOIN tblPersonalInfo Y
            ON X.ApplicantId = Y.ApplicantId 
        INNER JOIN tblCircular Z
            ON Y.Cirname = Z.Cirname  --(*)
--WHERE Z.Cirname=(Y.Cirname)   --.....maybe not required as the line above (*) deals with this
GROUP BY Y.ApplicantId,
        Y.Applicantname
```

Comment: thanks to replay..but i want to sum two queries like sum(T+T)T is sum another value & another T is other value

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any connection between subqueries `tblAcademicInfo` and `tblexperience` so you are creating a `CROSS JOIN` where every value from first is summed with every value from second. Maybe you should try adding `ApplicantId` to each subquery select list and use it to JOIN between them and with `tblPersonalInfo`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 

    t1+t2,

    tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId,
    tblPersonalInfo.Applicantname
FROM    
    (
        SELECT  
            tblexperience.ApplicantId
           ,SUM(tblExpeRange.score)as t2
        FROM tblexperience
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblExpeRange 
           ON tblexperience.ExpRange=tblExpeRange.expeRange
        GROUP BY tblexperience.ApplicantId
    ) tblexperience,
    INNER JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT  
             tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
            ,SUM(tblGradPoint.score) AS t1
        FROM tblAcademicInfo
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblGradPoint 
            ON tblAcademicInfo.cgpa=tblGradPoint.[cgpa/division]
        GROUP BY tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
    ) tblAcademicInfo ON tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId = tblexperience.ApplicantId
    INNER JOIN tblPersonalInfo ON tblexperience.ApplicantId = tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId 
    INNER JOIN tblCircular 
        ON tblPersonalInfo.Cirname = tblCircular.Cirname
```

EDIT: also, don't you think this query would look much more readable if you use Common Table Expressions and Aliases:

```
WITH CTE_Experience AS 
(
    SELECT  
        e.ApplicantId
        ,SUM(er.score) AS t2
    FROM tblexperience e
        LEFT JOIN tblExpeRange er ON e.ExpRange = er.expeRange
    GROUP BY e.ApplicantId
)
,CTE_AcademicInfo AS 
(
    SELECT  
         ai.ApplicantId
        ,SUM(gp.score) AS t1
    FROM tblAcademicInfo ai
        LEFT JOIN tblGradPoint gp ON ai.cgpa = gp.[cgpa/division]
    GROUP BY ai.ApplicantId
)
SELECT
    ai.t1 + ex.t2,
    pin.ApplicantId,
    pin.Applicantname
FROM tblPersonalInfo pin 
    INNER JOIN CTE_Experience ex ON ex.ApplicantId = pin.ApplicantId
    INNER JOIN CTE_AcademicInfo ai ON ai.ApplicantID = pin.ApplicantId
    INNER JOIN tblCircular ci ON ci.Cirname = pin.Cirname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId,
   tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantName,
   (tblExperience.t2+tblAcademicInfo.t1) as d
FROM tblPersonalInfo
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT SUM(tblExpeRange.score) as t2,
       tblExperience.ApplicantId
   FROM tblExperience
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tblExpeRange
       ON tblExperience.ExpRange=tblExpeRange.ExpRange
   GROUP BY tblExperience.ApplicantId
)tblExperience ON tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId=tblExperience.ApplicantId
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT SUM(tblGradPoint.score) as t1,
       tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
   FROM tblAcademicInfo
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tblGradPoint
       ON tblAcademicInfo.cgpa=tblGradPoint.[cgpa/division]
   GROUP BY tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
)tblAcademicInfo ON tblPersonalInfo.ApplicantId=tblAcademicInfo.ApplicantId
INNER JOIN tblCircular
   ON tblPersonalInfo.Cirname=tblCircular.Cirname
```